# Performance consideration and design a dimension that partition a cube

Tags: ssas, cube, dimensions, ssas-2012

As we know When a cube is built, tuples are created by dimensions and some aggregations applied. Know I faced with a special type of dimension that it's members aren't collectable. For example please consider actor type dimension:

```
Code                Desc
----------------------------------
1                  Vendor
2                  Employee
3                  Unemployed
```

The point is that I never want to aggregation for `Vendor or Employee` or `Vendor or Employee or Unemployed`. My problem is just about comparing these items with together. I only want to compare `Vendor` with `Employee` or `Employee` with `Unemployed`. So I think in cube there are some aggregations that I don't need to them.

Is there any way to handle this dimension? Is there any dimension type?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

For the beginning you don't need ALL member in attribute hierarchy, so you could set IsAggregatable property to false.

[image]

But, this will not prevent aggregation if you select for example two members (Employee and Vendor) in the filter. For this purpose you will need some kind of scope assignment against your dimension.